# Why is join not executed by default

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm wondering why is `join()` not done by default on the thread in all cases when we do not explicit detach thread? Wouldn't it spare lots of trouble and avoid joining treads where exception could happen or programmer just forget about it?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: If you forgot about a thread you have a bug. Hiding that bug is not helpful.

Comment: Why would you expect such actually?

Comment: What about if you want to start 5 threads then join them all in a loop? Could you do that with your implementation?

Comment: Joining a thread halts its execution until the thread to join to ends. Allowing it as default behavior would just break behavior since a thread would start and immediately halt.